# Material Table Expand Row React

Tags: reactjs, material-table

[UI image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGdOJ.png)

Is there any way for me to expand the row and render different components below the current row based on the button pressed (View Part Details / View Quotation)

```
<Fragment>
  <MaterialTable
    components={{
      Container: props => <Paper {...props} elevation={0} />
    }}
    title={null}
    columns={user.creditType === "credit" ? columns : nonCreditColumns}
    data={allParts}
    options={{
      search: false,
      sorting: false,
      actionsColumnIndex: -1,
      headerStyle: {
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0,
        color: colors.titleBlue,
        fontSize: "11pt",
        fontWeight: 600
      },
      rowStyle: { color: colors.fontGrey, fontSize: "11pt" },
      toolbar: false,
      showTitle: false,
      paging: false
    }}
  />

</Fragment>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

U can use the [detail panel in material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel)